# Apache NiFi - PutGCSObject on custom directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, apache-nifi, pipeline

I'm drawing a NiFi pipeline to move files from a remote filesystem to a bucket on Google Cloud Storage. The goal is to move files to specific folders (to be created automatically if they do not exist) in a bucket based on their name.
Entering the path (e.g. *bucketname/subdir*) as the processor's "bucket" property returns error.
Any of you have done this task before? How to upload files to a specific subfolder in a Google Cloud bucket?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to put the `subdir` as part of the **key** property on that processor -- GCS buckets are one level and all *objects* within can be [in subdirectories](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) but that path is part of the key. The key property supports NiFi Expression Language, so you can construct various keys based on flowfile attributes, etc. (e.g. `literalFolder/${subDirFromAttribute}/${filename}`).

Answer (score 0):

[@Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70465/andy) is correct, here's an example with visual:

Processor: **PutGCSObject**
[image]